# Bruhat-Tits tree as Cayley graph of free group

Tags: reference-request, lattices, trees, p-adic-numbers, cayley-graphs

$\DeclareMathOperator\BT{BT}\DeclareMathOperator\GL{GL}$Let $p > 2$ be a prime and $n = \frac{p + 1}{2}$. We can identify the vertices of Bruhat-Tits tree $\BT(\mathbb Q_p)$ with the elements in free group $F_n$ by interpreting $\BT(\mathbb Q_p)$ as a Cayley graph of $F_n$. I wonder is this correspondence merely a bijection of sets, or we can squeeze some more out of it ? For example:

1. Looking at vertices of $\BT(\mathbb Q_p)$ as (equivalence classes of) lattices, what lattice represents the product of two lattices as elements of $F_n$?
2. There is a quotient map $\pi : \GL_2(\mathbb Q_p) \to \BT(\mathbb Q_p)$, I wonder, what are the preimages of some "nice" normal subgroups of $F_n$ like $[F_n,F_n]$ ?
3. I guess we need to put some additional structure on $\BT(\mathbb Q_p)$ to indicate the "opposite" directions like $x$ and $x^{-1}$, where $x$ is one of the generators of $F_n$, but I'm not sure what geometric structure should correspond to it.

I'm not a specialist in algebraic geometry or number theory, any references will be much appreciated.

Comment: By the "Bruhat–Tits tree $\operatorname{BT}(\mathbb Q_p)$", do you mean the Bruhat–Tits building of $\operatorname{SL}_2$ over $\mathbb Q_p$?

Comment: This seems to be not clearly defined. When you write "by interpreting $\mathrm{BT}(\mathbf{Q}_p)$ as Cayley graph of $F_n$". If I understand correctly, you choose an isomorphism between this BT tree and this Cayley graph. But you have many choices (continuum many, actually). And all the sequel is very sensitive to this choice.

Comment: In addition, you might use some discrete copy of $F_n$ inside $\mathrm{PGL}_2(\mathbf{Q}_p)$, but there are many such choices, and even one choice being made, there are many choices of $n$-element generating subsets (and no obvious best choice, I believe).

Comment: @YCor you are right, there is no canonical choice of such bijection of course. Let's fix some vertex of $BT(\mathbb Q_p)$ which will map to an identity in $F_n$, then we need to specify how adjacent vertices map to generators (and their inverses) and so on. We can fix a basis in $\mathbb Q_p^2$ such that the distinct vertex will be represented by an identity matrix, if this will help. I agree that the question is partially about possibility of choosing the bijection which interplays nicely with a group structure.

Comment: @YCor can you please explain a bit about "some discrete copy of $F_n$ inside $PGL_2(\mathbb Q_p)$ ? Are there some distincitve choices, like Sanov representation of $F_2$ in $SL_2(\mathbb Z)$ perhaps ?

Comment: @LSpice I was following the definition in Section 2 of https://www.math.mcgill.ca/goren/667.2010/Atefeh.pdf

Comment: I meant "some discrete subgroup of $\mathrm{PGL}_2(\mathbf{Q}_p)$ that is isomorphic to $F_n$". And it cannot be contained in $\mathrm{PGL}_2(\mathbf{Z})$, since the latter has compact closure.